# Redux-Saga - cancel all other sagas when cancel action is fired

Tags: redux-saga

In my project I have a root saga that watches several actions and makes some API calls.
In some cases I want to cancel those sagas and API calls.

Now it is composed like that:

```
export default function*() {
  yield all([
    takeLatest(ActionTypes.GET_ACTION_ONE, getOneSaga),
    takeLatest(ActionTypes.GET_ACTION_TWO, getTwoSaga),
  ]);
}
```

And I have `ActionTypes.CANCEL`, and when it's fired I want any other saga (`getOneSaga` and `getTwoSaga`) to be cancelled and I want to manage `yield cancelled()` to cancel API calls inside them.

So, how do I compose all of my actions and cancel action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`race`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#raceeffects) effect:

```
export default function* () {
  yield race([
    take(ActionTypes.CANCEL),
    all([
      takeLatest(ActionTypes.GET_ACTION_ONE, getOneSaga),
      takeLatest(ActionTypes.GET_ACTION_TWO, getTwoSaga),
    ]),
  ]);
}
```

> Creates an Effect description that instructs the middleware to run a *Race* between multiple Effects. When resolving a *Race*, the middleware automatically **cancels all the losing** Effects

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I've found with the help of [this issue](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/988)

```
export default function*() {
  while (true) {
    const allTasks = yield all([
      takeLatest(ActionTypes.GET_ACTION_ONE, getOneSaga),
      takeLatest(ActionTypes.GET_ACTION_TWO, getTwoSaga),
    ]);
    yield take(ActionTypes.CANCEL);
    yield all(allTasks.map((task: Task) => cancel(task)));
  }
}
```